# Twitter4j: count mentions of a user

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I need to get a count of how many times a user have been mentioned by others (publicly at least).
While there's no straightforward way to get it for a user from [`User`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/User.html) Class, I decided to use [`Query`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Query.html) and by searching for a username, count the number of results:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
Query query = new Query("@xxxx");
QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
System.out.println(result.getCount());
```

This didn't work as the method [`QueryResult#getCount()`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/QueryResult.html#getCount--) actually returns the limit set at [`Query`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Query.html) (15 by default), which means I'll have to use [`QueryResult#getTweets()`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/QueryResult.html#getTweets--) to get the count as such:

```
result.getTweets().size()
```

While this works, a few accounts and I'd exhaust my Twitter API quota by reaching the [limit](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting).

What could be a possible work around, knowingly mentions are not required, but their count only?